# using breakpoints for the first time

Tags: iphone, html, css, breakpoints

Hi all I am using breakpoints for the first time and I had them working fine, but now my site adapts to the mobile layout but not the screen-size for mobile! I can't see any unclosed tags or css erros, any clue what could be causing this?

http://bennyfit.co.uk/

best,

Comment: What does breakpoints have to do at all with your adapting screen size and CSS layout?  Is your code hitting and stopping at a breakpoint and waiting for you to respond in the debugger?  Without you explaining some link between breakpoints and CSS layout, this question will get closed as unclear what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting your css through a validator. This usually shows up errors that are hard to spot normally:

http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/

Comment: Thanks for that, I find that really hard to follow, not sure what to look for.

Comment: You have lot of lines which say '*zoom:'? This is not valid.

Comment: @markt - zoom was a common IE work-around in older versions of IE: http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/z/zoom/

Comment: why is there an asterisk before it? That shouldn't be there.

Comment: I have not put any fixes in for IE yet. It is strange as it has been working fine and I have tested it on my mobile. I have made lots of changes today and I think its just a an unclosed tag or CSS error but just can;t find it! Thanks for that site though, IE is the next thing to do!